# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "product_provider"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am facing an issue with Sequelize migrations in a Node.js project with PostgreSQL. I have two tables: 'product_provider' and 'source_number'. I want to add foreign key constraints on 'product_id' and 'provider_id' columns in the 'source_number' table, referencing the 'product_id' and 'provider_id' columns in the 'product_provider' table, respectively.

I added a unique constraint for the combination of 'product_id' and 'provider_id' in the 'product_provider' table. However, when running the migration for the 'source_number' table, I still encounter the error: "there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table 'product_provider'."

I have verified the unique constraint in the 'product_provider' table and checked for any duplicate data. The Sequelize configuration seems correct, and I'm using the correct database driver.

Here's the migration code:

```
// product_provider migration
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('product_provider', {
      product_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true },
      provider_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true },
    });
    // Unique constraint code here
  },
  // Down function here
};

// source_number migration
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('source_number', {
      // Other columns...
      product_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'product_provider',
          key: 'product_id',
        },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      provider_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'product_provider',
          key: 'provider_id',
        },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      },
      // Other columns...
    });
  },
  // Down function here
};
```

I've made sure completely that the constraint is being applied by viewing the database from pgAdmin4.7. The error, however, still persists.

Comment: You should read the manual https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/

Comment: I think you are describing one foreign key covering both columns. It looks like you might be creating two foreign keys for one column each. Neither column is unique in its own.

Comment: And Sequelize does not support much composite PKs and foreign keys